# css content goes out of div

Tags: css

Hi I have page http://rygol.cz/qlife/ and when Iam zooming out the content goes out of his div. If i you height: auto; or height: 100% its ok but leftcolumn is smaller then right, clear doesnt help me.
Have anybody some idea how to fix it?

```
#leftcolumn { 
 color: #333;
 background: #fff;
 background-image:url("./images/corner.png");
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 padding: 10px;
 height: 800px;
 width: 244px;
 float: left;
}
#rightcolumn { 
 float: right;
 color: #333;
 background: #fff;  
 padding: 10px;
 height: 800px;
 width: 638px;
 display: inline;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Any possibility you could rephrase what the problem is? It's very hard to understand. The page looks fine in my browser

Comment: You cannot control the zoom of the browser.

Comment: It looks great but when you zoom out, the content goes out from div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need that extra space between header and the content you should just go ahead and place the *#leftcolumn* and *#rightcolumn* in an additional wrapper container with the background-color set and have the *#container* without the background-color set.

**HTML** structure:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content-wrapper">
      <div id="leftcolumn"></div>
      <div id="rightcolumn"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And **CSS**:

```
#container {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 922px;
}

#header {
color: #333;
background: #fff;
width: 902px;
padding: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
height: 200px;
}

#content-wrapper {
background-color: #fff;
min-height: 1px;
overflow: hidden; /* clear hack :) */
}

#leftcolumn {
color: #333;
background: #fff;
background-image: url("./images/corner.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 10px;
width: 244px;
float: left;
}

#rightcolumn {
float: right;
color: #333;
background: #fff;
padding: 10px;
width: 638px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I need space between heather and those two columns and speace between columns and footer. If i use your css there will #fff on all container :(

Comment: I edited the answer. If I copied it right, that should be it. It would have been much easier for both of us if you used jsFiddle or something like that in the first place.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height declarations in the columns. You could also use `overflow-y: scroll` though I would stick to removing the heights. Another thing to consider is that people generally don't zoom out that far anyway: the text becomes impossible to read at the zoom level it breaks at (chrome v24).

If you want equal height columns have the shorter column floated to one side then set `position: relative` and `top: 0; bottom: 0;` then set the other column to have `overflow: hidden;` to 'clear' the float. Note: the floated column should come first in the markup for this to work.

Comment: This doesn't work :( But yes, I want to have same height for both columns. The problem isn't from zooming out, but if you connect projector to computer you will see that problem...

Comment: You need to rethink your markup I think. Would be easier than forcing what you have already. As a rule, never set a height on elements that can have a variable amount of content.